# Highlighting the country on the map when you hover over

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

I want to highlight the country when I hover over it. To do this, I took QStandardItemModel with the polygons of the desired countries.
The problem is that the onClicked event works as expected, but onEntered and onExited fire in the rectangle, at the extreme coordinates, and not in the polygon. Is it possible for onEntered and onExited to work in the same area as onClicked? Perhaps there is some other solution for highlighting countries? I looked towards MaskedMouseArea but as a resource you need to set QImage. Thanks in advance for any help.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGeoPolygon>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QQmlContext>

class PolygonItem: public QStandardItem
{
public:
    PolygonItem(QString Name, const QGeoPolygon &polygon);
    QString Name() const;
    QGeoPolygon polygon() const;
};

class PolygonItemModel: public QStandardItemModel{
public:
    PolygonItemModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    void addPolygonItem(PolygonItem *item);
};

enum PolygonRole{
    NameRole,
    GeopolygonRole,
    };

PolygonItem::PolygonItem(QString name, const QGeoPolygon &polygon):
    QStandardItem()
{
    setData(name, NameRole);
    setData(QVariant::fromValue(polygon), GeopolygonRole);
}

PolygonItemModel::PolygonItemModel(QObject *parent):
    QStandardItemModel(parent)
{
    setItemRoleNames({{NameRole, "name"},
    {GeopolygonRole, "polygon"}});
}

void PolygonItemModel::addPolygonItem(PolygonItem *item)
{
    appendRow(item);
}

const std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> Namibia =
{
    {
        {14.52484512329101562,-22.69206619262695312},
        {14.52739906311035156,-22.6679534912109375},
        {14.52458286285400391,-22.62903022766113281},
        {14.51138877868652344,-22.5527801513671875},
        {14.41638755798339844,-22.33444595336914062},
        {14.38763809204101562,-22.28347396850585938},
        {14.28583145141601562,-22.1233367919921875},
        {14.127777099609375,-21.94055557250976562},
        {14.10249900817871094,-21.91403007507324219},
        {14.04249954223632812,-21.86222457885742188},
        {13.95267200469970703,-21.77889060974121094},
        {13.96798419952392578,-21.73465538024902344},
        {13.95666599273681641,-21.70194625854492188},
        {13.93555545806884766,-21.67444610595703125},
        {13.87791538238525391,-21.59458541870117188},
        {13.70111083984375,-21.296112060546875},
        {13.57694435119628906,-21.12916946411132812},
        {13.40388774871826172,-20.86236381530761719},
        {13.38499832153320312,-20.8244476318359375},
        {13.19888877868652344,-20.23833465576171875},
        {13.17499923706054688,-20.18083572387695312},
        {13.15972137451171875,-20.15472412109375},
        {13.14027595520019531,-20.13111114501953125},
        {13.11666584014892578,-20.11507225036621094},
        {13.08444404602050781,-20.09944534301757812},
        {13.05569267272949219,-20.07361221313476562},
        {13.04194355010986328,-20.04639053344726562},
        {13.03027725219726562,-20.00139236450195312},
        {12.989166259765625,-19.90944671630859375},
        {12.9797210693359375,-19.89139175415039062},
        {12.97027587890625,-19.8733367919921875},
        {12.9444427490234375,-19.82389068603515625},
        {12.92777633666992188,-19.789306640625},
        {12.81194305419921875,-19.59833526611328125},
        {12.79138755798339844,-19.56500244140625},
        {12.77333641052246094,-19.539093017578125},
        {12.70722198486328125,-19.41777801513671875},
        {12.69861030578613281,-19.399169921875},
        {12.68805503845214844,-19.36944580078125},
        {12.6399993896484375,-19.26166915893554688},
        {12.58694267272949219,-19.15250015258789062},
        {12.5422210693359375,-19.067779541015625},
        {12.46083259582519531,-18.92805862426757812},
        {12.4416656494140625,-18.899169921875},
        {12.41874885559082031,-18.86652946472167969},
        {12.30666542053222656,-18.71722412109375},
        {12.29083251953125,-18.70083427429199219},
        {12.23083305358886719,-18.6505584716796875},
        {12.21360969543457031,-18.63861465454101562},
        {12.19666481018066406,-18.62694549560546875},
        {12.17458248138427734,-18.61277961730957031},
        {12.14611053466796875,-18.59305572509765625},
        {12.12555503845214844,-18.57777786254882812},
        {12.08305454254150391,-18.53555679321289062},
        {12.02083206176757812,-18.47111129760742188},
        {11.99791622161865234,-18.41333580017089844},
        {11.99749946594238281,-18.37430572509765625},
        {11.95305442810058594,-18.26583480834960938},
        {11.94388866424560547,-18.24777984619140625},
        {11.89235973358154297,-18.1805572509765625},
        {11.84708309173583984,-18.13916778564453125},
        {11.80722141265869141,-18.08625221252441406},
        {11.76763820648193359,-17.98819541931152344},
        {11.76111030578613281,-17.9618072509765625},
        {11.741943359375,-17.83028030395507812},
        {11.7324981689453125,-17.7619476318359375},
        {11.71666526794433594,-17.56416702270507812},
        {11.71638870239257812,-17.5391693115234375},
        {11.71722221374511719,-17.483612060546875},
        {11.72055435180664062,-17.45722579956054688},
        {11.73222160339355469,-17.372222900390625},
        {11.74777603149414062,-17.32972335815429688},
        {11.74972152709960938,-17.30916976928710938},
        {11.75373554229736328,-17.26501083374023438},
        {11.75278282165527344,-17.25483322143554688},
        {11.81166553497314453,-17.2702789306640625},
        {11.88458251953125,-17.22444725036621094},
        {11.9022216796875,-17.20583343505859375},
        {11.93305397033691406,-17.18069648742675781},
        {11.97611045837402344,-17.1641693115234375},
        {12.04805374145507812,-17.143890380859375},
        {12.08777618408203125,-17.13652992248535156},
        {12.20583152770996094,-17.19472503662109375},
        {12.23805427551269531,-17.21527862548828125},
        {12.2922210693359375,-17.22972488403320312},
        {12.43416595458984375,-17.21277999877929688},
        {12.47888755798339844,-17.241668701171875},
        {12.557220458984375,-17.24333572387695312},
        {12.60444259643554688,-17.22583389282226562},
        {12.81791591644287109,-17.10708427429199219},
        {12.85138702392578125,-17.07250213623046875},
        {12.87979030609130859,-17.04014015197753906},
        {12.92333221435546875,-17.01639175415039062},
        {12.98583221435546875,-16.99111175537109375},
        {13.01847171783447266,-16.978057861328125},
        {13.14916610717773438,-16.95417022705078125},
        {13.17090129852294922,-16.95631980895996094},
        {13.20888710021972656,-16.97361373901367188},
        {13.26083183288574219,-16.98486328125},
        {13.31777763366699219,-16.978057861328125},
        {13.34630966186523438,-16.97066879272460938},
        {13.37604045867919922,-16.97090530395507812},
        {13.47208213806152344,-17.01083564758300781},
        {13.49430465698242188,-17.02555656433105469},
        {13.52801895141601562,-17.0875701904296875},
        {13.66069316864013672,-17.21889114379882812},
        {13.69777679443359375,-17.24139022827148438},
        {13.84138870239257812,-17.32361221313476562},
        {13.92888832092285156,-17.40111160278320312},
        {13.99321937561035156,-17.42394638061523438},
        {14.01666545867919922,-17.4109039306640625},
        {14.05110931396484375,-17.41944503784179688},
        {14.082916259765625,-17.43000221252441406},
        {14.17138767242431641,-17.42111396789550781},
        {14.19472122192382812,-17.41139030456542969},
        {14.21805381774902344,-17.3869476318359375},
        {14.36166572570800781,-17.3872222900390625},
        {14.44805526733398438,-17.38750076293945312},
        {14.63472175598144531,-17.388336181640625},
        {14.99388885498046875,-17.3897247314453125},
        {15.49694442749023438,-17.38944625854492188},
        {15.58305454254150391,-17.38916778564453125},
        {15.9566650390625,-17.38666915893554688},
        {16.00333023071289062,-17.38666915893554688},
        {16.606109619140625,-17.39083480834960938},
        {17.27883148193359375,-17.39222335815429688},
        {17.51055526733398438,-17.39194488525390625},
        {17.56166458129882812,-17.39083480834960938},
        {17.73388671875,-17.38888931274414062},
        {18.00054931640625,-17.38616943359375},
        {18.11722183227539062,-17.3869476318359375},
        {18.1888885498046875,-17.3872222900390625},
        {18.3899993896484375,-17.3869476318359375},
        {18.4515380859375,-17.38983535766601562},
        {18.51333236694335938,-17.4727783203125},
        {18.57833099365234375,-17.57222366333007812},
        {18.64194107055664062,-17.6480560302734375},
        {18.7536773681640625,-17.74527931213378906},
        {18.80430412292480469,-17.768890380859375},
        {18.91944313049316406,-17.81638908386230469},
        {18.98388671875,-17.8259735107421875},
        {19.0258331298828125,-17.8300018310546875},
        {19.0558319091796875,-17.82777786254882812},
        {19.11680221557617188,-17.81944656372070312},
        {19.13360977172851562,-17.80437660217285156},
        {19.1752777099609375,-17.80111312866210938},
        {19.24555397033691406,-17.80625152587890625},
        {19.29874801635742188,-17.82500076293945312},
        {19.33721923828125,-17.84389114379882812},
        {19.413330078125,-17.861114501953125},
        {19.445831298828125,-17.86278152465820312},
        {19.55916595458984375,-17.86750030517578125},
        {19.701385498046875,-17.87055587768554688},
        {19.79791450500488281,-17.86375236511230469},
        {19.81860923767089844,-17.85805702209472656},
        {19.92055511474609375,-17.8572235107421875},
        {19.94624710083007812,-17.86333465576171875},
        {19.97131729125976562,-17.88014030456542969},
        {20.01694107055664062,-17.89083480834960938},
        {20.09888839721679688,-17.89638900756835938},
        {20.12888717651367188,-17.89444732666015625},
        {20.244720458984375,-17.88014030456542969},
        {20.27083206176757812,-17.8612518310546875},
        {20.32131767272949219,-17.8572235107421875},
        {20.44520378112792969,-17.90187644958496094},
        {20.4925537109375,-17.94189071655273438},
        {20.55367851257324219,-17.98305702209472656},
        {20.59555435180664062,-17.98139190673828125},
        {20.63846969604492188,-17.97847366333007812},
        {20.75194168090820312,-17.99611282348632812},
        {20.781585693359375,-18.01020431518554688},
        {20.85416412353515625,-18.01639175415039062},
        {20.88972091674804688,-17.99444580078125},
        {20.95333099365234375,-17.96826553344726562},
        {21.02138519287109375,-17.95333480834960938},
        {21.13861083984375,-17.9344482421875},
        {21.16586685180664062,-17.93146705627441406},
        {21.23687362670898438,-17.93889045715332031},
        {21.26333045959472656,-17.95639228820800781},
        {21.37935638427734375,-18.01488876342773438},
        {21.75540542602539062,-17.94734573364257812},
        {22.29027557373046875,-17.85000228881835938},
        {22.5641632080078125,-17.79888916015625},
        {22.88110733032226562,-17.73944473266601562},
        {22.90999984741210938,-17.73333358764648438},
        {22.99638748168945312,-17.71694564819335938},
        {23.28472137451171875,-17.66250228881835938},
        {23.28916549682617188,-17.66111373901367188},
        {23.47610855102539062,-17.62583541870117188},
        {23.820831298828125,-17.56027984619140625},
        {24.02902603149414062,-17.51958465576171875},
        {24.23908615112304688,-17.47843170166015625},
        {24.38124847412109375,-17.47347259521484375},
        {24.44013786315917969,-17.48236465454101562},
        {24.50249862670898438,-17.508056640625},
        {24.5422210693359375,-17.52500152587890625},
        {24.5654144287109375,-17.53347396850585938},
        {24.59027481079101562,-17.5338897705078125},
        {24.61916542053222656,-17.50583648681640625},
        {24.63819313049316406,-17.49666976928710938},
        {24.66388702392578125,-17.49361419677734375},
        {24.70861053466796875,-17.4983367919921875},
        {24.81777572631835938,-17.51555633544921875},
        {24.91249847412109375,-17.54083633422851562},
        {24.96999740600585938,-17.559722900390625},
        {24.98430442810058594,-17.58389091491699219},
        {25.029998779296875,-17.6100006103515625},
        {25.065277099609375,-17.624725341796875},
        {25.25194168090820312,-17.78305816650390625},
        {25.26443099975585938,-17.80224990844726562},
        {25.25237846374511719,-17.79570960998535156},
        {25.17937469482421875,-17.78208541870117188},
        {25.13638687133789062,-17.79656410217285156},
        {25.09909439086914062,-17.82784843444824219},
        {25.06638717651367188,-17.83222579956054688},
        {25,-17.8260498046875},
        {24.97277450561523438,-17.82111358642578125},
        {24.93610763549804688,-17.81389236450195312},
        {24.83277511596679688,-17.83770942687988281},
        {24.67916488647460938,-17.9441680908203125},
        {24.56631660461425781,-18.05423736572265625},
        {24.52416610717773438,-18.06000137329101562},
        {24.49791336059570312,-18.05930709838867188},
        {24.47360992431640625,-18.03277969360351562},
        {24.45194244384765625,-17.99916839599609375},
        {24.439788818359375,-17.97805595397949219},
        {24.41694259643554688,-17.9537506103515625},
        {24.38833236694335938,-17.94583511352539062},
        {24.36305427551269531,-17.94916725158691406},
        {24.26888656616210938,-18.013336181640625},
        {24.00666427612304688,-18.16777801513671875},
        {23.96722030639648438,-18.18500137329101562},
        {23.91222000122070312,-18.23694610595703125},
        {23.88694000244140625,-18.26476287841796875},
        {23.87041473388671875,-18.26305770874023438},
        {23.84402656555175781,-18.29000282287597656},
        {23.39805221557617188,-18.17611312866210938},
        {23.3630523681640625,-18.12722396850585938},
        {23.32999801635742188,-18.07638931274414062},
        {23.32583236694335938,-18.04500198364257812},
        {23.31638717651367188,-18.01541900634765625},
        {23.29710769653320312,-17.99594879150390625},
        {23.28711318969726562,-17.99633598327636719},
        {23.0777740478515625,-18.00444793701171875},
        {22.63721847534179688,-18.086669921875},
        {22.5,-18.11126708984375},
        {22.26221847534179688,-18.15389251708984375},
        {21.81694412231445312,-18.23833465576171875},
        {21.46249771118164062,-18.30444717407226562},
        {21.23555374145507812,-18.31194686889648438},
        {20.9932861328125,-18.31841659545898438},
        {20.99361038208007812,-18.33861160278320312},
        {20.99416351318359375,-18.47555923461914062},
        {20.99416351318359375,-18.69527816772460938},
        {20.9935302734375,-19.17194747924804688},
        {20.99307632446289062,-19.99822235107421875},
        {20.9933319091796875,-20.179168701171875},
        {20.99280929565429688,-20.82427215576171875},
        {20.99303054809570312,-20.99245071411132812},
        {20.99249649047851562,-21.018890380859375},
        {20.99249649047851562,-21.32222366333007812},
        {20.99277496337890625,-21.59722518920898438},
        {20.99277496337890625,-21.94194793701171875},
        {20.99277496337890625,-21.96944808959960938},
        {20.991943359375,-21.9969482421875},
        {20.91777420043945312,-21.9983367919921875},
        {20.64971923828125,-22},
        {20.30833053588867188,-22.00139236450195312},
        {20.0004730224609375,-22.00156402587890625},
        {19.99666595458984375,-22.00500106811523438},
        {19.9961090087890625,-22.08750152587890625},
        {19.99721908569335938,-22.26694488525390625},
        {19.99759483337402344,-22.5},
        {19.99749755859375,-22.722503662109375},
        {19.99777603149414062,-22.94333648681640625},
        {19.99827766418457031,-22.95992088317871094},
        {19.99860763549804688,-22.97083663940429688},
        {19.9988861083984375,-23.12277984619140625},
        {19.9989013671875,-23.30869674682617188},
        {19.99944305419921875,-23.45417022705078125},
        {20,-23.64750289916992188},
        {20.000274658203125,-23.75722503662109375},
        {20.00053787231445312,-23.864410400390625},
        {20,-23.950836181640625},
        {20.00055313110351562,-24.28222274780273438},
        {20.00111007690429688,-24.40639114379882812},
        {20.00194168090820312,-24.57222366333007812},
        {20.00222015380859375,-24.7241668701171875},
        {20.0016632080078125,-24.76555633544921875},
        {20.00094223022460938,-24.76540756225585938},
        {20.0016632080078125,-24.79361343383789062},
        {20.0016632080078125,-24.86278152465820312},
        {20.0013885498046875,-25.08361434936523438},
        {20.00055313110351562,-25.22166824340820312},
        {20.000274658203125,-25.41500091552734375},
        {20.00043487548828125,-25.61648941040039062},
        {20,-25.8708343505859375},
        {20,-26.40916824340820312},
        {19.99944305419921875,-27.03028106689453125},
        {19.99916458129882812,-27.32027816772460938},
        {19.9987640380859375,-27.36949920654296875},
        {19.99833297729492188,-27.48583602905273438},
        {19.99805450439453125,-27.58222579956054688},
        {19.99777603149414062,-27.8719482421875},
        {19.99833297729492188,-28.06500244140625},
        {19.99805450439453125,-28.35472488403320312},
        {19.9969482421875,-28.41558647155761719},
        {19.81221961975097656,-28.49250221252441406},
        {19.78972053527832031,-28.49555778503417969},
        {19.74360847473144531,-28.48555564880371094},
        {19.56745719909667969,-28.52833175659179688},
        {19.51333236694335938,-28.595001220703125},
        {19.49388885498046875,-28.633056640625},
        {19.490692138671875,-28.66902923583984375},
        {19.46638870239257812,-28.6997222900390625},
        {19.44777679443359375,-28.71083450317382812},
        {19.41833114624023438,-28.71889114379882812},
        {19.34902572631835938,-28.73583602905273438},
        {19.32249832153320312,-28.72750282287597656},
        {19.30138587951660156,-28.72541999816894531},
        {19.27721977233886719,-28.73125267028808594},
        {19.26124763488769531,-28.74486160278320312},
        {19.23978996276855469,-28.80243110656738281},
        {19.24805450439453125,-28.83166885375976562},
        {19.25999832153320312,-28.85541915893554688},
        {19.25388717651367188,-28.899444580078125},
        {19.18388748168945312,-28.93722343444824219},
        {19.14583015441894531,-28.9550018310546875},
        {19.10833168029785156,-28.96187591552734375},
        {19.00249671936035156,-28.92791938781738281},
        {18.98569107055664062,-28.90500068664550781},
        {18.97041511535644531,-28.8776397705078125},
        {18.95152473449707031,-28.86639022827148438},
        {18.71916389465332031,-28.83653068542480469},
        {18.3383331298828125,-28.8844451904296875},
        {18.18131637573242188,-28.90847206115722656},
        {18.04444313049316406,-28.86812591552734375},
        {18.02610969543457031,-28.84986305236816406},
        {18.0013885498046875,-28.82694625854492188},
        {17.96992874145507812,-28.80409812927246094},
        {17.91249847412109375,-28.77916717529296875},
        {17.74972152709960938,-28.74639129638671875},
        {17.7108306884765625,-28.7566680908203125},
        {17.67930412292480469,-28.76986312866210938},
        {17.64340019226074219,-28.77396202087402344},
        {17.60527610778808594,-28.75312614440917969},
        {17.6022186279296875,-28.72069549560546875},
        {17.58975791931152344,-28.68954277038574219},
        {17.49777603149414062,-28.69472503662109375},
        {17.46110916137695312,-28.70277786254882812},
        {17.27881622314453125,-28.23826408386230469},
        {17.21881294250488281,-28.24207305908203125},
        {17.1986083984375,-28.22361373901367188},
        {17.18437004089355469,-28.20049667358398438},
        {17.18833160400390625,-28.17165756225585938},
        {17.18902015686035156,-28.11410903930664062},
        {17.17165756225585938,-28.102264404296875},
        {17.15413856506347656,-28.09749794006347656},
        {17.13430404663085938,-28.08708572387695312},
        {17.12041473388671875,-28.06541824340820312},
        {17.10791397094726562,-28.04583549499511719},
        {17.07576179504394531,-28.0303497314453125},
        {16.91187286376953125,-28.06750297546386719},
        {16.88694190979003906,-28.09236335754394531},
        {16.82249832153320312,-28.23778152465820312},
        {16.80159568786621094,-28.3627777099609375},
        {16.77666473388671875,-28.44166946411132812},
        {16.71951103210449219,-28.49902915954589844},
        {16.70062255859375,-28.49034881591796875},
        {16.67711639404296875,-28.46430587768554688},
        {16.62499618530273438,-28.49611282348632812},
        {16.48958969116210938,-28.57817840576171875},
        {16.451629638671875,-28.61462020874023438},
        {16.39332962036132812,-28.59111404418945312},
        {16.35444259643554688,-28.56277847290039062},
        {16.17194366455078125,-28.399169921875},
        {16.15805435180664062,-28.38389205932617188},
        {16.11722183227539062,-28.33750152587890625},
        {16.04972076416015625,-28.26639175415039062},
        {16.02319145202636719,-28.241668701171875},
        {15.99749946594238281,-28.22916793823242188},
        {15.97333145141601562,-28.21500015258789062},
        {15.89861106872558594,-28.16278076171875},
        {15.75638771057128906,-28.03416824340820312},
        {15.73611068725585938,-28.01111221313476562},
        {15.68972206115722656,-27.95611190795898438},
        {15.67652606964111328,-27.929168701171875},
        {15.68270683288574219,-27.90909957885742188},
        {15.67138767242431641,-27.87347412109375},
        {15.64694404602050781,-27.84389114379882812},
        {15.60555458068847656,-27.79750251770019531},
        {15.57027626037597656,-27.76722335815429688},
        {15.55249977111816406,-27.75444793701171875},
        {15.53104114532470703,-27.73041915893554688},
        {15.52194309234619141,-27.6818084716796875},
        {15.53110980987548828,-27.66146087646484375},
        {15.5191650390625,-27.62694549560546875},
        {15.39916610717773438,-27.4550018310546875},
        {15.36055374145507812,-27.40722274780273438},
        {15.29416656494140625,-27.32250213623046875},
        {15.28722190856933594,-27.30222320556640625},
        {15.264373779296875,-27.21472358703613281},
        {15.26999855041503906,-27.16222381591796875},
        {15.23527717590332031,-26.96944427490234375},
        {15.21861076354980469,-26.93666839599609375},
        {15.20221996307373047,-26.92333412170410156},
        {15.17916488647460938,-26.9183349609375},
        {15.15777587890625,-26.90277862548828125},
        {15.11249923706054688,-26.7838897705078125},
        {15.09499931335449219,-26.73527908325195312},
        {15.08402633666992188,-26.69687652587890625},
        {15.07972145080566406,-26.65000152587890625},
        {15.09402751922607422,-26.63416862487792969},
        {15.13173484802246094,-26.63170242309570312},
        {15.13680458068847656,-26.67465400695800781},
        {15.16666603088378906,-26.6233367919921875},
        {15.17180442810058594,-26.60166740417480469},
        {15.13110923767089844,-26.47861480712890625},
        {15.11736011505126953,-26.44708633422851562},
        {15.0880889892578125,-26.40316390991210938},
        {15.04749870300292969,-26.375},
        {15.02319431304931641,-26.36486244201660156},
        {14.991943359375,-26.35361480712890625},
        {14.96986007690429688,-26.34014129638671875},
        {14.95916557312011719,-26.30805587768554688},
        {14.94736003875732422,-26.13736343383789062},
        {14.97430419921875,-26.13020896911621094},
        {14.98166656494140625,-26.08889007568359375},
        {14.98083305358886719,-26.06347465515136719},
        {14.96944427490234375,-26.01416778564453125},
        {14.95749855041503906,-25.98777961730957031},
        {14.93555545806884766,-25.9630584716796875},
        {14.91527652740478516,-25.93680763244628906},
        {14.83777618408203125,-25.7619476318359375},
        {14.8343048095703125,-25.74194717407226562},
        {14.84916496276855469,-25.63361167907714844},
        {14.86472129821777344,-25.59028053283691406},
        {14.88090133666992188,-25.56729316711425781},
        {14.84097099304199219,-25.41861343383789062},
        {14.82999897003173828,-25.40139198303222656},
        {14.81708240509033203,-25.37916946411132812},
        {14.80097103118896484,-25.28042030334472656},
        {14.81166553497314453,-25.25333404541015625},
        {14.83416557312011719,-25.1875},
        {14.85777664184570312,-25.08722305297851562},
        {14.85666561126708984,-25.05888938903808594},
        {14.83888816833496094,-25.01139068603515625},
        {14.83207321166992188,-24.99943923950195312},
        {14.467498779296875,-23.15513992309570312},
        {14.68944358825683594,-23.20444488525390625},
        {14.71277618408203125,-23.16055679321289062},
        {14.690277099609375,-23.07305908203125},
        {14.66805458068847656,-22.98416900634765625},
        {14.66944313049316406,-22.93194580078125},
        {14.6659698486328125,-22.63843727111816406},
        {14.64430522918701172,-22.63916778564453125},
        {14.53888702392578125,-22.6833343505859375},
        {14.52484512329101562,-22.69206619262695312}
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    PolygonItemModel model;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("polygonmodel", &model);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    QGeoPolygon polygon;

    for (int i = 0; i < Namibia.size(); i++)
    {
        polygon.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(Namibia[i].second, Namibia[i].first));
    }

    PolygonItem *item = new PolygonItem("Namibia", polygon);
    model.addPolygonItem(item);
    return app.exec();
}
```

qml

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(45.137451890638886, -68.13734351262877)
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "osm"

        }
        zoomLevel: 1

        MapItemView{
            model: polygonmodel
            delegate: MapPolygon {
                color: "blue"
                border.color: "green"
                border.width: 1
                smooth: true
                opacity: 0.25
                geoShape: model.polygon

            MouseArea{
              anchors.fill: parent
              hoverEnabled : true
              onEntered:
              {
                  border.color = "red"
                  border.width =3
              }
              onExited:
              {
                  border.color = "white"
                  border.width = 1
              }
              onClicked:
              {
                    console.log("onClicked:")
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```